# Cast and Fail Compilation if a narrowing conversion is possible

Tags: c++, casting, c++14, type-safety, narrowing

In order to prevent "unexpected issues", with format specifies where types are defined in other modules, I'm looking for a cast operator which will *fail to compile* on a narrowing conversion: this represents a fundamental type error that needs to be addressed.

For example, a using in some external header that has recently been changed from a compatible type to an incompatible type:

```
 namespace y {
   using X = uint64_t; // "recent change", was previously int32_t
 }
```

The goal is to get this to fail (error not warning-as-error), as the result is used as `"%d`.

```
 y::X a; // question covers ANY value in domain of X, not if overflow at run-time
 int32_t r = cast_that_fails_to_compile_if_can_narrow<int32_t>(a);

 // So this is guaranteed to always be a valid type specifier
 // (per http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)
 // for the provided argument if the cast/code above compiles.
 printf("%d", r);
```

(In this case the intractable narrowing issue should be handled by additional code changes.)

Comment: I'm not aware of anything in the std lib but should be easy to do with a template using static assert and checking sizes. Are you looking for something like that?

Comment: @doug As long as it fits in C++14 :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initialization with braces (but not parentheses) disallows narrowing conversions:

```
int32_t r{a};
// or
int32_t r = {a};
// or
auto r = int32_t{a};
```

Your compiler may be allowing this anyway, but that is not standard-conform <sup>[1]</sup>. E.g. for GCC you need to add the `-pedantic-errors` flag for it to actually generate a hard error.

Also note that the type for `%d` should be `int`. If you use `int32_t` instead, you are risking a similar issue should a platform use a differently sized `int`.

You can use it directly in the `printf` call:

```
printf("%d", int{a});
```

---

<sup>[1] The standard always only requires compilers to print *some* diagnostic. It does not require hard errors preventing the compilation of the program. GCC for example only warns by-default, but that is still conforming.</sup>

Comment: Nice! I like this on printf where the types are unclear. Useful broadly and especially on var arg functions like printf. I've also found some compilers will warn on this when the format string is a const.

Comment: Thanks, that clean usage directly in the `printf` is fits the case here. Was hoping for a mandated hard-error - I'll see how it plays on our builds later today, as a clear warning would be sufficient for purposes. How does the compiler know the difference between the {..} and (..) forms? Is that compiler magic or does it feed to a different ctor (could it even?)?

Comment: @user2864740 It is probably good practice to use `-pedantic-errors` on GCC and Clang or `/fpermissive-` on MSVC anyway to force stricter standard conformance and portability (as long as you aren't intentionally using any of the compiler extensions this disables). With that it should be a hard error on all compilers and as I mentioned a warning should at least be required.

Comment: The difference between `{..}` and `(..)` is that they are different initialization syntax with different rules. They may behave completely different in some context (e.g. calling different constructors for class types) and they have more subtle difference such as these narrowing rules and order of evaluation of individual elements in the initializer list, different parsing rules (see *most vexing parse*), etc. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization for all the details on initialization in C++. It is quite a mess.

Answer (score 1):

A template function can be made to check for narrowing casts but permit other static casts:

```
template <typename Tto, typename Tfr>
Tto static_cast_prohibit_narrow(Tfr v)
{
    static_assert(sizeof(Tfr) <= sizeof(Tto), "Narrowing cast prohibited");
    return static_cast<Tto>(v);
}
```

The compiler produces an error encountering a narrow cast while permitting other static_casts.

```
int main()
{
    long long int i1{ 4 };
    int i2{ 5 };
    //i2 = static_cast_prohibit_narrow<int>(i1); // Compiler static_assert error
    i1 = static_cast_prohibit_narrow<int>(i2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it also possible to catch signed/unsigned difference? eg. suppose the name was 
 `cast_same_size_and_signedness` to require a more strict check than first presented in the question.

Comment: @user2864740 Sure. Check out the type traits provided in std. You can check against all sorts of things to limit conversions however you like and there is no run time hit or code generated.